# Accessing the Mura Component Bean from a Plugin

Tags: coldfusion, content-management-system, mura

I am working on a Mura plugin that uses a mura tag to pull in a component and use it on the page.  Essentially my plugin needs to call `$.dspObject('component',Arguments.componentid)`.  Since the mura scope isn't available within the plugin method then I am guessing that I need to pull in a component bean, but I have no idea how to do that.

```
<cffunction name="showPlayer" access="public" output="false" returntype="String">
    <cfargument name="component" type="string" required="true" hint="The ID of the component that contains the playlist." />

    <!--- Create the body content --->
    <cfsavecontent variable="bodycode">
        <cfoutput>#$.dspObject('component',Arguments.component)#</cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
</cffunction>
```

That is a very stripped down version of the method (the full eventHandler can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/davidlong03/mura-music-player/blob/e440c7681ff84046fddccbb24dac605ce4757838/eventHandlers/EventHandler.cfc).

So how would I rewrite my code to pull the component bean out (or whatever I need to do for it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways possible:

```
<cfargument name="$">
```

OR

```
var $=application.ServiceFactory.getBean(“muraScope”);
```

OR

```
var $=getServiceFactory().getBean(“muraScope”);
```

OR

```
   var $=getBean(“muraScope”);
```

See [MuraCMS Programmers Guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/43795547/Programmers-Guide-MuraCMS) and [cfobject.cfc](http://svn.blueriver.com/mura/trunk/www/requirements/mura/cfobject.cfc)